# Show Custom Customer Fields in Checkout

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I've succesfully managed to add custom fields to the customer. However I need these fields to show up in onepage checkout.

I've overridden `Mage_Customer_Block_Widget_Name` and created my own `customer/widget/name.phtml`, added the attributes in  the `sql/xxx_setup/installer-x.y.z.php` (added them to `adminhtml_customer`, `customer_account_edit`, `checkout_register` and `customer_account_create`) and they work fine in the admin site, however they just wont work on the checkout form. The field shows up, <strike>but it has the wrong value and no label</strike>.

I'm clueless why does it work in the customer registration form but doesn't in the checkout.

The installer code to add the attribute is:

```
$attributes = array(
    'lastname2' =>  array(
        'frontend_label'=>'Apellido Materno',
        'label' => 'Apellido Materno',
        'input' => 'text',
        'type'  => 'varchar',
        //System =  False and visible true = Show in 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit', 'checkout_register'
        'system'=>true,
        'visible'=>true, //Watch out!! Only visible fields get processed by the form controllers!!!
        'user_defined'=>false,
        'used_in_forms' => array('adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_edit', 'checkout_register','customer_account_create'),
        'required' => 0,
        'position' =>69
    ));


foreach($attributes as $attribute_code=>$definition)
    {
        $installer->addAttribute('customer', $attribute_code,  $definition); 

        /**
        * @var Mage_Eav_Model_Config
        */
        Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
        ->getAttribute('customer', $attribute_code)
        ->setData('used_in_forms',$definition['used_in_forms'])
        ->save();
    }
```

The code in name.phtml is

```
<div class="<?php echo $this->getContainerClassName()?>">
    <?php if ($this->showPrefix()): ?>
        <div class="field name-prefix">
            <label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('prefix')?>"<?php if ($this->isPrefixRequired()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php if ($this->isPrefixRequired()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('prefix') ?></label>
            <div class="input-box">
                <?php if ($this->getPrefixOptions() === false): ?>
                    <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('prefix')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('prefix')?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getPrefix()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('prefix') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('prefix') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
                    <?php else: ?>
                    <select id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('prefix')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('prefix')?>" title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('prefix') ?>" class="<?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('prefix') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?>>
                        <?php foreach ($this->getPrefixOptions() as $_option): ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $_option?>"<?php if ($this->getObject()->getPrefix()==$_option):?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->__($_option)?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="field name-firstname">
        <label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('firstname')?>" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('firstname') ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('firstname')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('firstname')?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getFirstname()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('firstname') ?>" maxlength="255" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('firstname') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php if ($this->showMiddlename()): ?>
        <?php $isMiddlenameRequired = $this->isMiddlenameRequired(); ?>
        <div class="field name-middlename">
            <label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('middlename')?>"<?php echo $isMiddlenameRequired ? ' class="required"' : '' ?>><?php echo $isMiddlenameRequired ? '<em>*</em>' : '' ?><?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('middlename') ?></label>
            <div class="input-box">
                <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('middlename')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('middlename')?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getMiddlename()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('middlename') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('middlename') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="field name-lastname">
        <label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('lastname')?>" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('lastname') ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('lastname')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('lastname')?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getLastname()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('lastname') ?>" maxlength="255" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('lastname') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field name-lastname">
        <label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('lastname2')?>"><?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('lastname2') ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('lastname2')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('lastname2')?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getLastname2()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('lastname2') ?>" maxlength="255" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('lastname2') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php if ($this->showSuffix()): ?>
        <div class="field name-suffix">
            <label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('suffix')?>"<?php if ($this->isSuffixRequired()) echo ' class="required"' ?>><?php if ($this->isSuffixRequired()) echo '<em>*</em>' ?><?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('suffix') ?></label>
            <div class="input-box">
                <?php if ($this->getSuffixOptions() === false): ?>
                    <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('suffix')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('suffix')?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getSuffix()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('suffix') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('suffix') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
                    <?php else: ?>
                    <select id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('suffix')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('suffix')?>" title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('suffix') ?>" class="<?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('suffix') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?>>
                        <?php foreach ($this->getSuffixOptions() as $_option): ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $_option?>"<?php if ($this->getObject()->getSuffix()==$_option):?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->__($_option)?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Concerning the value: You wrote `$this->getObject()->getLastname()` instead of `$this->getObject()->getLastname2()`

Comment: Thanks Simon, still nothing shows up :(

Comment: Which value should show up? At this point the customer isn't registered yet, so there is no lastname to display. The fields are only visible on `customer_account_create`. Is there a problem with saving the name?

Comment: @SimonH The path I'm running is the customer is already registrered and he's registering his billing and shipping addresses. So his lastname should appear there

Comment: Oops. Just to correct myself. It should show lastname2's value, which is filled in by the customer at the time of registration

Comment: Ah, ok. This are address attributes, not customer attributes. So you need to load them differently. For registered users you could use `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getLastname2()` but it won't be saved to your address, as there is no attribute yet.

Comment: @SimonH So I need to add this as customer/address attributes as well so they get stored and shown in the billing/shipping addresses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fields in the checkout you are talking about are address attributes, not customer attributes. So you need to load them differently. For registered users you could use `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getLastname2()` but it won't be saved to your address, as there is no attribute yet.

Depending on where you want lastname2 to be accessible you can create corresponding attributes for the entities `customer_address`,`quote_address` and `order_address`. They are created the same way you did for `customer` with

```
$installer->addAttribute($entityName, $attribute_code,  $definition);
```

But that's not all. For the attributes to be converted correctly you need to set up conversion rules in your module config.xml. See for example the configuration of `Mage_Sales`. 
In the `global` node there is a node `fieldsets` with the corresponding rules. There is a node `customer_address` to convert address attributes to quote address attributes. In `sales_convert_quote` there are rules to convert this attributes to order attributes.

So for your attributes to be accessible in all you config should look like this:

```
<global>
   <fieldsets>
      <customer_address>
         <lastname2>
            <to_quote_address>*</to_quote_address>
         </lastname2>
      </customer_address>
      <sales_copy_order_billing_address>
         <lastname2>
            <to_order>*</to_order>
         </lastname2>
       <sales_copy_order_billing_address>
       <sales_copy_order_shipping_address>
         <lastname2>
            <to_order>*</to_order>
         </lastname2>
       </sales_copy_order_shipping_address>
       <sales_convert_quote_address>
           <lastname2>
              <to_order_address>*</to_order_address>
              <to_customer_address>*</to_customer_address>
           </lastname2>
       </sales_convert_quote_address>
       <sales_convert_order_address>
            <lastname2>
               <to_quote_address>*</to_quote_address>
            </lastnam2e>
       <sales_convert_order_address>
       <customer_address>
           <lastname2>
              <to_quote_address>*</to_quote_address>
           </lastname2>
       </customer_address>
   </fieldsets>
</global>
```