# Save custom attribute to order object at Checkout in Magento - How can I confirm this?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, observers

I've been having trouble with this for a few days, essentially I need to add a custom **organisation_id** attribute (that I have created via an installer script) to be added to both the **customer** object and **order** object at the end of the onepage checkout.

The installer script works fine (I can see the values within the eav_attribute and core_resources table in the database.

During the checkout phase on the final 'Order Review' section, once the **Place Order** button is clicked this executes the following observer:

```
sales_order_place_after
```

Once this has been executed it runs the following function within an Observer:

```
public function afterOrderPlaced($observer)
{
    // this id below comes from a select dropdown within the checkout onepage & already saved to session
    $organisation_id = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerOrganisationId();

    $this->_order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $this->_order->setOrganisationId($organisation_id)->save(); // e.g 25621

    // Customer stuff
    $this->_customer_id = $this->_order->getCustomerId();
    $this->_customer = $this->_order->getCustomer();
    $this->_customer->setOrganisationId($organisation_id)->save(); // e.g 25621
}
```

In this instance, I simply want to set the **organisationId** value on both the customer and order objects to '25621'.

Once I have completed the checkout process and hit the 'order confirmation' page I'd like to be able to confirm this **organisation_id** has indeed been correctly added to the customer and order object, can anyone confirm the easiest/best way to do this? I presume this will need to include some modification to the admin html for Sales to include this information as well.

Please note - My Magento skillset is rather limited

My Installer Script below:

```
$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup();
$installer->startSetup();

$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup();
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'organisation_id', array(
    'input'         => 'select', //or select or whatever you like
    'type'          => 'int', //or varchar or anything you want it
    'label'         => 'Organisation ID',
    'visible'       => 1,
    'required'      => 0, //mandatory? then 1
    'user_defined'  => 1,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
));

$installer->addAttribute('quote', 'organisation_id', array(
    'input'         => 'select', //or select or whatever you like
    'type'          => 'int', //or varchar or anything you want it
    'label'         => 'Organisation ID',
    'visible'       => 1,
    'required'      => 0, //mandatory? then 1
    'user_defined'  => 1,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
));

$installer->addAttribute('order', 'organisation_id', array(
    'input'         => 'select', //or select or whatever you like
    'type'          => 'int', //or varchar or anything you want it
    'label'         => 'Organisation ID',
    'visible'       => 1,
    'required'      => 0, //mandatory? then 1
    'user_defined'  => 1,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
));

$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: The approach with the fieldset conversion could be used here, too. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19892930/2455224

Comment: You are missing the attribute for quote and order. They are separate entities. Add them with `$installer->addAttribute('quote','organisation_id', array(...);` and `$installer->addAttribute('order', 'organisation_id' array(...);`. The table columns should be created automatically.

Comment: @SimonH - i have changed my script, would this appear correct?

Comment: I've tried my new installer script and get a Wrong entity ID error? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your custom value in your database `sales_flat_order_address` table and `sales_flat_quote_address` table .

Let me know if you have any query

Comment: hi keyur, sorry could confirm where about those two values are in the database or the admin? thanks again

Comment: @Zabs of-course you can find this value in your database ,, please see my updated answer .Let me know if you have any query

Comment: I have looked at both the two tables - I presume there should be a column named 'organisation_id' within either or both of these tables? Not sure if I have done something wrong but I don't seem to see any column named 'organisation_id' - any ideas?

Comment: Please update your question with the corresponding installscripts for this attributes.

Comment: Thanks @SimonH I have included my installer script